# getting unknown column when trying to move between multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

This is my code

```
Select Lname,ISBN, Title
From Author, Books
Where Books.ISBN=BookAuthor.ISBN
AND Author.AuthorID=BookAuthor.AuthorID
```

It keeps telling me:

> unknown column 'BookAuthor.ISBN' in 'where clause'

I've tried writing this backward and forward any help or explanation would be amazing thank you.

Comment: Table  `BookAuthor` does not appear in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Table  `BookAuthor` does not appear in the `FROM` clause. Presumably, you  are missing a `join`:

```
select a.lname, b.isbn, b.title
from author a
inner join bookauthor ba on ba.isbn     = a.isbn
inner join books      b  on b.author_id = ba.author_id
```

Note that this query uses standard, explicit joins, rather than old-school, implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause): this very old syntax is much harder to follow and should not be used in new code.